# cfgrid moves around on the page when selecting a row

Tags: coldfusion, cfgrid

I have a cfgrid set up, and it works well when sorting and returning the correct information. The problem is that when I return a longer list that extends the page, and I select a row, I skip to another area of the returned list. It still selects the row when clicked on, but will end up somewhere else on the list so that I have to scroll down to find it. I want the page to just stay where it is and still select the row like it has been. I have messed with preservedataonsort, and anything else that may be related, but with no luck. Any thoughts to accomplish this? Thanks

```
    <cfgrid format="HTML" name="tblbaseNEWNEWGRID" query="HOMEFILTERQRY" 
             selectmode="" colheaderbold="true" sort="true" selectcolor="red" selectonload="no" gridlines="yes"   > 

            <cfgridcolumn name="B" width="74" headeralign="center" dataalign="center" />    
            <cfgridcolumn name="W" width="159" headeralign="center" dataalign="center" />           
            <cfgridcolumn name="START" width="57" header="START" headeralign="center" dataalign="center" type="date"  />
            <cfgridcolumn name="END" width="57" header="END" headeralign="center" dataalign="center" type="date"  />
            <cfgridcolumn name="POH" width="57" header="POH" headeralign="center" dataalign="center" type="date" />
            <cfgridcolumn name="INSTALL" width="135" header="INSTALL" headeralign="center" dataalign="center"/>
            <cfgridcolumn name="ST" width="65" headeralign="center" dataalign="center"/>        
            <cfgridcolumn name="PREV" width="105" header="PREVIOUS REASON" headeralign="center" dataalign="center">
            <cfgridcolumn name="ES" width="75" header="COMPANY" headeralign="center" dataalign="center"/>
            <cfgridcolumn name="ES" width="62" header="PUM" headeralign="center" dataalign="center"/>
            <cfgridcolumn name="PUM" width="65" header="SET " headeralign="center" dataalign="center" type="numeric" />
            <cfgridcolumn name="ESP_D" width="48" Header="DH?" headeralign="center" dataalign="center"/>
            <cfgridcolumn name="PROVING" width="48" header="PR?" headeralign="center" dataalign="center" />
            <cfgridcolumn name="MOTO" width="88" header="MOTO" headeralign="center" dataalign="center"/>
            <cfgridcolumn name="COMMENTS" width="88" headeralign="center" dataalign="center"/>
            <cfgridcolumn name="ADDED_BY" display="NO" values="#session.AD_User#" >
            <cfgridcolumn name="ADDED_DATE" display="NO" values="#now()#" >     
            <cfgridcolumn name="EVENT_NUM" width="50" header="EVENT NUMBER" headeralign="center" dataalign="center" select="no" />

</cfgrid>
```

Comment: We need to see some code and some information on what you have tried to fix the issue.

Comment: I have looked at options for the cfgrid tag, such as preservedataonsort, or something along the lines of onselect. It always returns to the top of the grid when a row is selected. I just cannot find anything that effects it when added or taken out, and cannot think of why it would be returning to the top of the grid every time.